# Should take no action after hitting submit button (Adobe Livecycle)

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

The objective of this problem is to pop a warning message if user hit submit button with no address and take no action, but the problem is submit button don't have click event.

I am checking a address field, if the address field has some value then it should proceed to submit the form, otherwise it should popup a message and don't take any action.

```
 Form.#pageSet[0].Page1.FOOTER_EN_FRAGMENT.FSSUBMIT_PC::mouseUp - (JavaScript, client)

    var addr1 = HEADER_EN_FRAGMENT.CUSTOMER_ML_ADDRESS_1.rawValue;
    var addr2 = HEADER_EN_FRAGMENT.CUSTOMER_ML_ADDRESS_2.rawValue;

        if(addr1  == null || addr1  == "" || addr2 == null || addr2  == "")
        {
          app.alert("Address field can't be blank!",3); 
          FSSUBMIT_PC.validate = "disable";//need help here
        }
```

Right now its just displaying the error message, but still submitting when button is click. I want it to take no action but I don't know how to do that in adobe livecycle designer.

Also please tell me if there is any other way to pop up error message other than app alert.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what I learned each button has 3 control type regular, execute and submit. In submit and execute button type we can have click event so what we need to do, add a second button with control type regular and place it over the first button with control type submit and in second button click even call first button,

```
 var addr1 = form1.Page1.HEADER.CUSTOMER_ML_ADDRESS_1.rawValue;
 var addr2 = form1.Page1.HEADER.CUSTOMER_ML_ADDRESS_2.rawValue;

 if(addr1 == null || addr1 == "" || addr2 == null || addr2 == "")
 {
    xfa.host.messageBox("Address field cannot be blank.");  
 }
 else
 {
      FSSUBMIT_PC.execEvent("click");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like that I think:

```
var addr1 = HEADER_EN_FRAGMENT.CUSTOMER_ML_ADDRESS_1;
var addr2 = HEADER_EN_FRAGMENT.CUSTOMER_ML_ADDRESS_2;

if(addr1.isNull || addr2.isNull)
{
    app.alert("Address field can't be blank!",3); 
    xfa.event.cancelAction = 1; //This worked for me for cancelling the print process, maybe it will work for you too!
}
```

And I wonder why you did it in the `mouseUp`-event, and not in `click`.

`App.alert` ist usually the quickest way but if you want to try out different stuff I recommend reading about custom dialogs - e.g. [here](http://adobelivecycledesignercookbookbybr001.blogspot.de/2013/10/using-appexecdialog-in-adobe-designer.html).
There's also an older `xfa` version: [MessageBox Docu](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=001219.html).

Comment: mouse click event was not highlighted don't know why. So I wasn't able to select mouse click

Comment: usually it should "cancelAction" should automatically come but it didn't cameup and it didn't worked for me.

Comment: it makes sense, because on "mouseUp" it should've already be finished submitting it - the reason might be that you're using a special "submit-button". On regular buttons you wouldn't have all of those problems but you would need to submit it manually.

Comment: you could try it out in the event before the submit: "mouseDown"

Comment: what I noticed if your button-  submit, then you won't get click event.